# Solution of a system of differential equations

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

we have the following system ($\nu >0$)

\begin{cases}
a(t)\tau'(t)= \nu a(t) \alpha^2(t)\\
\alpha'(t)+\alpha(t) b(t)=0\\
\beta'(t) +\alpha(t) c(t)=0\\
b'(t)+b^2(t) -1=0\\
a'(t)+b(t) a(t)=0\\
c'(t)+b(t)c(t)=1\\
a^2(t) \alpha(t) = -2 \nu a(t) \alpha^2(t)
\end{cases}

I find that a solution of this system is:  $b(t)=-1$, $a(t)=-2 \nu e^t$, $c(t)=e^t-1$, $\beta(t)= e^t(1-1/2 e^t)$, $\tau(t)= \dfrac{\nu}{2} e^{2t}$.

My result is true? Please.

Thank's in advance to the help.

Comment: You should be able to check whether your solution works, but you have to go through all seven of your equations to check them. It shouldn't take that long though.

Comment: yes i did it, but i search a confirmation please.